# Using Route Attribute with Html.Action C# MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, routes

I have the following application hierarchy:

> Area > Website > HomeController > HeaderAction

Once I decorated my controller action with a route attribute, the @Html.Action in my Layout View stopped working

```cs
[RouteArea("Website", AreaPrefix = "Home"), Route("{action}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("~/header", Name = "head")]
   public ActionResult Header()
   {
      WebsiteModel model = new WebsiteModel();
      return PartialView(model);
   }

}
```

```
@Html.Action("head")
```

Now I have to use AreaRegistration instead
Does anyone know what my problem is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you get when you use @Html.Action("head")?

Comment: Also, if you put a Url.Action("head") in your page, what is the url that gets rendered?

Comment: Yep, when I put the Url.Action("head") Its normaly. But when I use @Html.Action("head") into _Layout.cshtml and refresh page. Raise error: "System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.'"

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you defined your route as `[Route("~/header", Name = "head")]` which make the route relative to the base application path. In your code you use `@Html.Action("head")` which uses the *name* of the route you defined instead of the actual route.

Try changing it to

```
@Html.Action("header")
```

Comment: Noway to call @Html.Action when using [RouteArea("Website", AreaPrefix = "Home"), Route("{action}")]. I Tried all way then nothing working. Anyway, thank you for your concerts.